# Wie soll ich es auf Deutsch sagen: "I will get back to you"?

Tags: business-correspondence

I want to reply to an e-mail sent, later. How can I say this to sender?

I saw

> Ich kehre zurück am 10.10.2020

but *"kehren"*? why is *"werden"* not used?

Could I use that or do you have any better suggestion?

Comment: We need more context. The phrase "I will get back to you" can mean different things in different situations in English (*"I am physically going away and then move back"* or *"I am doing other things now and then deal with your issue again"*) and this different meanings have different German translations.

Comment: Looks like you caught a false friend there. "Ich kehre zurück" means "I will return (physically)", not "I will get back (to your problem)".

Comment: These are rather two questions. One: What is the German phrase for "I will get back to you", and two: "why present tense instead of future tense"?

Comment: I want to learn two different expressions:

One is "I'm on vacation and I'm not available right now." Because of that I want to say like "I will get back to you next week" or "I will return next week".

The other is "I have some work to deal with right now and I'm not available right now." Because of that I want to say like "I will get back to you next week" or "I will return next week".

And I say these words in e-mail. I guess that German has different expressions for face-to-face contact and e-mail contact. I would like to learn both of them.
- -Sorry, I just saw your detailed answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sentence *"I will get back to you"* can mean:

1. > I left you physically, and after I was somewhere else, I will move back to your location.
2. > I was doing some other stuff, but later then I will think about your issue again.

The translations are:

1. > Ich werde zu dir zurückkehren.
2. > Ich werde auf dich zurückkommen.

But for #2 a more common phrase is in use:

> Ich werde mich bei dir melden.
>   Ich melde mich bei dir.
>   *literally: (I will contact you.)*

---

### about tenses

What you wrote what you have seen in German can not be the translation of the english sentence, because in English there is no date, but in German there is one. This makes a big difference!

In German the tense named **Gegenwart** or **Präsens** can not only be used to describe things that happen in the present like in this example:

> Es regnet jetzt.
>   I's raining now.

It also can used for something in the past, if it lasts up to the present:

> Ich lebe schon seit 50 Jahren in Österreich.
>   I've been living in Austria for 50 years.

You also use this tense for things that have no connection to any certain point in time:

> Kugeln sind rund.
>   Spheres are round.

And, you also can use this tense for events that will happen in the future, if there is no doubt that this event really will happen, and if you add the information, at which time in the future it will happen:

> **Morgen** stehe ich etwas früher auf.
>   **Tomorrow** I will get up a little bit earlier.
>
> **Im November** kaufe ich mir einen neuen Wintermantel.
>   I will buy a new winter coat **in November.**
>
> Ich kehre **am 10.10.2020** zurück.
>   I will return **on 10.10.2020.**

But it also is allowed to use **Zukunft** (also called **Futur I**) in this cases:

> Morgen werde ich etwas früher aufstehen.
>   Im November werde ich mir einen neuen Wintermantel kaufen.
>   Ich werde am 10.10.2020 zurückkehren.

Without the additional time specifications, all this examples will be understood as if the actions was going on now:

> Ich stehe ich etwas früher auf.
>   I'm getting up a little bit earlier.
>
> Ich kaufe ich mir einen neuen Wintermantel.
>   I'm buying a new winter coat.
>
> Ich kehre zurück.
>   I'm returning.

Answer (score 3):

This phrase in the given context would be translated best as

> Ich melde mich am 10. Oktober bei Ihnen.
>   Ich melde mich nach dem 10. Oktober bei Ihnen.
>   Ich melde mich um 13 Uhr bei Ihnen.
>   Ich melde mich ab/nach 13 Uhr bei Ihnen.

Please note that in German in many cases we tend to not use the Future I even though the action is clearly going to take place in the future. The fact that it's going to take place in the future is clear from context.

> **Ich werde mich** ... bei Ihnen **melden**

is grammatically correct, no question, but it still sounds overly formal.

**EDIT**
@UserUnknown noted that "noch einmal" makes it sound like you had contacted the other party before. I've removed it from the examples above.

One example where you'd use "noch einmal" could be when you tried to reach someone on the phone, but he was not available. In that case you could say:

> Ich melde mich nach 13 Uhr noch einmal bei Ihnen.

**EDIT II**
The phrase "Ich kehre am 10.10.2020 zurück" is used in automatic email responses to indicate when you'll be available again. As I noted above, in German we tend to not use the Future I even though the action takes place in the future.

Comment: Wieso immer "noch einmal"? Hat er sich schon mal bei ihm gemeldet?

Comment: Ich bin stillschweigend davon ausgegangen, dass es bei dem ursprünglichen "Get back to you" darum ging, etwas rückzufragen und sich dann noch einmal zu melden. Ich passe meine Antwort entsprechend an.